# Printing different number of columns in table using FPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I would like to create a table using FPDF that have 3 columns and a different number of rows.

This is current function that I use:

```
function MyTable($header, $data){
$w = array(63, 63, 63);
for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
$this->Cell($w[$i],4,$header[$i],1,0,'L');
$this->Ln();


foreach($data as $row)
{
$x=$this->GetX();
$y=$this->GetY();
$push_right = 0;

foreach($row as $col){
$this->Cell($push_right,4,$col,'LR');
$this->Ln();
}
$push_right = $x + 63;
$this->SetXY($push_right,97);
}
$this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');}
```

And call:

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',16);
$header = array('Alergije','Hronicne bolesti','Rizici');
$data = array(array('Penicilin','Latex'),array('Hipertenzija','Dijabetes','Secer'),array('Rizik 1','Rizik 2','Rizik 3','Rizik 4'));
$pdf->MyTable($header,$data);
$pdf->Output();
```

Current output is this:
[image]

And I would like to be like this:

[image]

I have found that I need to use SetXY(), but that did not work as it supposed to.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

issue in this line `$this->SetXY($push_right,97);` you are not set position y, that's why the text is overwrite.

Try some thing like this

```
$a=25;//set your desired location
$this->SetXY($push_right,$a);
//$a=$a+10; //if you want then increment for your desired location
```